# What are the parameters of map.setCenter?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I can't reliably find a single documentation of the function where a second number is passed to it as a parameter. I have a code (from a book) that reads :

```
map.setCenter(loc, 20);
```

where loc is a `google.maps.LatLng` object. However, what is the number `(20)` fed to the function? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is (probably, since you don't provide context) from the deprecated and turned off [Google Maps JavaScript API v2.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info)

It allowed the center and zoom to be set in a single operation.

From [the documentation (on archive.org, since it was turned off May 2013 and the official documentation has been removed)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110407085309/http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2)

> **setCenter(center:GLatLng, zoom?:Number, type?:GMapType)** | None
>
> Sets the map view to the given center. **Optionally, also sets zoom level and map type**. The map type must be known to the map. See the constructor, and the method addMapType(). This method must be called first after construction to set the initial state of the map. It is an error to call operations on a newly constructed GMap2 object until after this function is invoked.

(**note:** there is a wrapper for v2 that allows some of the v2 functionality to continue to work, but if that breaks, don't expect it to be fixed...)

- [related issue in the issue tracker #10333](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10333)